# Option group on access form as query parameter

Tags: sql, ms-access

I am working in Access 2016 and I have a from that the user can select the training type the want to run the report on. All trainings has an option value of 1, Bloodborne has an option value of 2 and so on. I want to take the value of my form and pass it into a query so it will display all employees that took that training.

My form is View February Training and contains a option group within a frame that is called FrameAllorCurrent. My query contains the training field which I am able to filter with the following Like "68" Were 68 is the training ID from the training table.

I know I have to do something in the training field of the query along the lines of 
[forms]![View February Training].[FrameAllOrCurrent].Value = 2 
but how do I make it so when it equals 2 it makes the training field "68" and returns all my bloodborne trainings?

SQL Query:

```
SELECT CompletedTrainings.RecordID
    ,CompletedTrainings.Employee
    ,CompletedTrainings.Training
    ,CompletedTrainings.CompletedDate
    ,CompletedTrainings.ExpiredDate
    ,EmployeeInformation.Employee
    ,EmployeeInformation.Active
    ,Trainings.TrainingID
    ,Trainings.[Training Name]
FROM Trainings
INNER JOIN (
    EmployeeInformation INNER JOIN CompletedTrainings 
        ON EmployeeInformation.ID = CompletedTrainings.Employee
        ) ON Trainings.TrainingID = CompletedTrainings.Training
WHERE (((EmployeeInformation.Active) LIKE "-1"))
ORDER BY Trainings.[Training Name]
```

Comment: What (if anything) do you have so far? In this situation, we need something to work off of. For instance, are you trying to write this directly into an Access query with SQL, or perhaps through VBA?

Comment: SQL is setup for the query with this so far  SELECT CompletedTrainings.RecordID, CompletedTrainings.Employee, CompletedTrainings.Training, CompletedTrainings.CompletedDate, CompletedTrainings.ExpiredDate, EmployeeInformation.Employee, EmployeeInformation.Active, Trainings.TrainingID, Trainings.[Training Name]
FROM Trainings INNER JOIN (EmployeeInformation INNER JOIN CompletedTrainings ON EmployeeInformation.ID = CompletedTrainings.Employee) ON Trainings.TrainingID = CompletedTrainings.Training
WHERE (((EmployeeInformation.Active) Like "-1"))
ORDER BY Trainings.[Training Name]

Answer (score 0):

There are several solutions to this. But one way to do it would be:

```
SELECT CompletedTrainings.RecordID
    ,CompletedTrainings.Employee
    ,CompletedTrainings.Training
    ,CompletedTrainings.CompletedDate
    ,CompletedTrainings.ExpiredDate
    ,EmployeeInformation.Employee
    ,EmployeeInformation.Active
    ,Trainings.TrainingID
    ,Trainings.[Training Name]
FROM Trainings
INNER JOIN (
    EmployeeInformation INNER JOIN CompletedTrainings 
        ON EmployeeInformation.ID = CompletedTrainings.Employee
        ) ON Trainings.TrainingID = CompletedTrainings.Training
WHERE EmployeeInformation.Active LIKE "-1"
AND [Training Name] = 
    SWITCH (
        [Forms]![View February Training].[FrameAllOrCurrent] = 1, "Whatever 1 should be",
        [Forms]![View February Training].[FrameAllOrCurrent] = 2, "68",
        [Forms]![View February Training].[FrameAllOrCurrent] = 3, "If there's a 3... etc."
        )
ORDER BY Trainings.[Training Name]
```

NOTE: I am uncertain what your related field is, so its listed as `[Training Name]`, this also assumes the column is in `TEXT` format, based on your quotations earlier. If the data type is numeric, just remove the quotes.